# Drop-down menu contents hover color

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, web-deployment

I'm creating a website and want to do a drop-down menu with a hover background color. I've got the drop-down button to change color but I can't get the links inside the drop-down menu to change when I hover over them.

Comment: Submenu’s parent element style could be overriding the style you have written. Make sure the styles are properly prioritized.

Comment: Some code would be usefull

Answer (score 0):

Below is HTML and CSS, I have even made main button "MENU" on hover to display submenu - Home, About and Contact. Hope it helps \m/

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And Now the CSS Code

```
a{
text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
list-style: none;
}

li{
color: #fff;
background:  black; 
padding: 1rem;
position: relative;  
}

li a {
color: White;
}

li:hover {
background: Red;
}

ul li ul {
opacity: 0;
min-width: 5rem;
position: absolute;  
}

ul li ul:hover {
opacity: 1;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: please make sure to close " ul  ". I'm not sure why it isn't displaying here. Sorry for that.
Edit: I have edited the code. Cheers :) and yes you can style it any way you want, I just didn't go through all that.